# Set default controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to set the default controller in MVC4?

I've tried adding the below code to the Global.ascx but it said "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement", seems it can't find the "route", did I put it on the wrong place?

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file. This is where you will be able to configure routes in the way you want.

There, you will find code similar to this:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to put this code inside  `RouteConfig.cs` under `App_Start`.

check [ASP.NET MVC 4: Where Have All The Global.asax Routes Gone?](http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2012/06/23/ASPNET-MVC-4-Where-Have-All-The-Globalasax-Routes-Gone.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The answers suggesting to use `RouteConfig` are correct but a bit misleading. There's nothing magical about `RouteConfig`; it's just a class that you create, name, and locate according to convention.

The important part is what you typically *pass* to `RouteConfig`: `RouteTable.Routes`

The route table is available from anywhere within an ASP.Net application. For example, you could say:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute( "myroute", "apples", new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar" } );
}
```

and it would work just fine. Of course, you should only initialize routes on startup and follow the convention of `RouteConfig` for consistency.

But it's worth knowing *why* it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please change it in your RouteConfig.cs file